# Accessing HTML table row element from pandas dataframe

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code to generate html from pandas dataframe. I'm using JS to access each table row but getting an error.

```
  File "<fstring>", line 2
    var elem = array[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
def generate_html_main_page(dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
    # get the table HTML from the dataframe
    table_html = dataframe.to_html(table_id="table")
    # construct the complete HTML with jQuery Data tables
    html = f"""
    <html>
    <header>
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </header>
    <body>
    {table_html}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var array = document.getElementById("table").rows
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            var elem = array[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = "<a href='#test'>" + elem +"</a>"
            document.write(document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    # return the html
    return html
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an f-string to generate HTML, but the HTML also has `{`/`}` characters in it. So Python is trying to execute the body of your JavaScript `for` loop as Python code.

You can escape them as `{{`/`}}` when you want them to just be literal braces. Or use plain string concatenation (`html = '''...''' + table_html + '''...'''`).

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use both raw-string and f-string together and not have the `/` escape

```
html = rf"""..."""
```